# Format int method java

Tags: java, format, int

Is there any method for "formatting" an `int` this way:
Lets say I have a int with value 1000000. I want to set this `int` in a textview, but i want it to show like this 1 000 000 or 1.000.000. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html). I think it should teach you how to format your numbers, both integer and real numbers.

As for your specific question see here:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols unusualSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
unusualSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
unusualSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
String pattern = "#,###,###";
int value = 1000000;
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern, unusualSymbols);
String output = myFormatter.format(value);
System.out.println(value + " " + pattern + " " + output);
```

This prints out:

```
1000000 #,###,### 1.000.000
```

This is modified code from the examples in the same site. I demonstrate the format you wanted.

Comment: @Ukjent I added example of how you will achieve the formatting you wanted.